# Is there a way to use a for-loop to quickly create sublots in matplotlib and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, plot

I'm saving the daily stock price for several stocks in a Pandas Dataframe. I'm using python and Jupyter notebook.

Once saved, I'm using matplotlib to graph the prices to check the data.

The idea is to graph 9 stocks at at time in a 3 x 3 subplot.

When I want to check other stock tickers I have to mannualy change each ticker in each subplot, which takes a long time and seems inefficient.

¿Is there a way to do this with some sort of list and for loop?

Here is my current code. It works but it seems to long and hard to update. (Stock tickers are only examples from a vanguard model portfolio).

```
x = price_df.index
a = price_df["P_VOO"]
b = price_df["P_VGK"]
c = price_df["P_VPL"]
d = price_df["P_IEMG"]
e = price_df["P_MCHI"]
f = price_df["P_VNQ"]
g = price_df["P_GDX"]
h = price_df["P_BND"]
i = price_df["P_BNDX"]



# Plot a figure with various axes scales
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

# Subplot 1
plt.subplot(331)
plt.plot(x, a)
plt.title("VOO")
plt.ylim([0,550])
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(332)
plt.plot(x, b)
plt.title("VGK")
plt.ylim([0,400])
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(333)
plt.plot(x, c)
plt.title('VPL')
plt.ylim([0,110])
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(334)
plt.plot(x, d)
plt.title('IEMG')
plt.ylim([0,250])
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(335)
plt.plot(x, e)
plt.title('MCHI')
plt.ylim([0,75])
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(336)
plt.plot(x, f)
plt.title('P_VNQ')
plt.ylim([0,55])
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(337)
plt.plot(x, g)
plt.title('P_GDX')
plt.ylim([0,8])
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(338)
plt.plot(x, h)
plt.title('P_BND')
plt.ylim([0,200])
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(339)
plt.plot(x, i)
plt.title('P_BNDX')
plt.ylim([0,350])
plt.grid(True)

plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this implementation not work out in your case?

```
x = price_df.index
cols = ["P_VOO","P_VGK",...] #Populate before running
ylims = [[0,550],...] #Populate before running

# Plot a figure with various axes scales
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

# Subplot 1
for i, (col, ylim) in enumerate(zip(cols, ylims)):
    plt.subplot(331+i)
    plt.plot(x, price_df[col])
    plt.title(col.split('_')[1])
    plt.ylim(ylim)
    plt.grid(True)
```

Haven't run the code in my local, could have some minor bugs. But you get the general idea, right?

Comment: Also, `enumerate` on a list returns the index and the value.

Comment: On the other hand, `zip` is used when you want elements of two or more lists simultaneously. For eg. `zip([1,2,3], [2,3,4])` returns `(1,2)`, `(2,3)`, and `(3,4)`

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot) and enable `subplots`, set the `layout` and `figsize`:

```
axes = df.plot(subplots=True, title=df.columns.tolist(),
               grid=True, layout=(3, 3), figsize=(15, 10))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Or use [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) to set the layout then plot on those axes with [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot):

```
# setup subplots
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 10))
# Plot DataFrame on axes
df.plot(subplots=True, ax=axes, title=df.columns.tolist(), grid=True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

---

Sample Data and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(5)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, 100, (10, 9)),
                  columns=list("ABCDEFGHI"))
```

`df`:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
0  88  71  26  83  18  72  37  40  90
1  17  86  25  63  90  37  54  87  85
2  75  57  40  94  96  28  19  51  72
3  11  92  26  88  15  68  10  90  14
4  46  61  37  41  12  78  48  93  29
5  28  17  40  72  21  77  75  65  13
6  88  37  39  43  99  95  17  26  24
7  41  19  48  57  26  15  44  55  69
8  34  23  41  42  86  54  15  24  57
9  92  10  17  96  26  74  18  54  47
```

Comment: This also worked. Thank you. The answer disapeared for a few days for some reason.